# Change Notifier didnt update CheckBox inside List after changing value?

Tags: flutter

I have this ListView widget that has checkboxes inside (everything is dynamic)
i have a system that stores the value of the checkboxes inside a list in the ListView State/controller.

[image]

I thought changing the value of the stored map would update the checkboxes but it didnt.

List State/Controller

```dart
class ListController with ChangeNotifier {
  ListController();

//<ColumnName, <Row, Value>
  Map<String, Map<int, bool>> _checkBoxValueMap = {};

  Map<String, Map<int, bool>> get checkBoxValueMap => _checkBoxValueMap;

  addCheckBoxValue(String columnName, int row, bool isEnabled) {
    Map<String, Map<int, bool>> tempCheckBoxValueMap = _checkBoxValueMap;
    if (tempCheckBoxValueMap[columnName] == null) {
      tempCheckBoxValueMap[columnName] = {};
    }
    tempCheckBoxValueMap[columnName]![row] = isEnabled;
    _checkBoxValueMap = tempCheckBoxValueMap;
  }

  setCheckBoxValue(String columnName, int row, bool isChecked) {
    Map<String, Map<int, bool>> tempCheckBoxValueMap = _checkBoxValueMap;
    tempCheckBoxValueMap[columnName]![row] = isChecked;
    _checkBoxValueMap = tempCheckBoxValueMap;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I stored the column and row key inside a map in map obj, and use setCheckBoxValue to set the value of each individual checkbox like this. (This is called outside of the list widget, after building and displaying it)

ControlStateList is where I store the List Controller.

```dart
ListController listController =
                    controlStateList["DetailsList"]!["State"] as ListController;
                listController.setCheckBoxValue("Approve", 1, true);
```

Here is the code for the checkbox widget, i add this while building the list

```dart
class ListCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  ListCheckBox({
    Key? key,
    required this.parentControlName,
    required this.parentController,
    required this.rowIndex,
    required this.columnName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String parentControlName;
  final ListController parentController;
  final int rowIndex;
  final String columnName;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ListCheckBoxState();
}

class ListCheckBoxState extends State<ListCheckBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PageLoader pageLoader = context.watch<PageLoader>();
    return Checkbox(
      value: widget.parentController
          .checkBoxValueMap[widget.columnName]![widget.rowIndex],
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
          widget.parentController.enable ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
      onChanged: (newValue) async {
        if (widget.parentController.enable) {
          await checkEditBoxChanges(pageLoader);
          //send request
          Map<String, String> requestData = {
            "Session": sessionInfo.sessionID,
            "ProgramID": pageLoader.pgmID!,
            "ControlName": widget.parentControlName,
            "SelectedRow": widget.rowIndex.toString(),
            "Data": newValue! ? "Y" : "",
            "FunctionKey": FunctionKeys.listCheckBox,
            "ColumnName": widget.columnName
          };
          await sessionInfo
              .sendRequest("EditData", requestData)
              .then((response) {
            widget.parentController
                .setCheckBoxValue(widget.columnName, widget.rowIndex, newValue);
            Map<String, dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(response);
            FormFunctions.processResponse(pageLoader, responseData,
                build: false);
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the part where I add the checkbox widget inside the list

```dart
widget.controller.addCheckBoxValue(
                  columnName, rowIndex + 1, rowDataListItem[columnName] == "Y");
              rowData.add(ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 20),
                child: Container(
                    width: Utility.getTextWidth("${longestItem[columnName]}ww",
                            StandardSize.font1) +
                        10,
                    child: ListCheckBox(
                      parentController: widget.controller,
                      parentControlName: widget.controlName,
                      rowIndex: rowIndex + 1,
                      columnName: columnName,
                    )),
              ));
```

Comment: can you include sample widget while using `ListController` that will reproduce the same error

Comment: can you add ur checkBox's code

Comment: @JBJason i have added the checkbox codes

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I will need some time to make an sample that can cause this issue, the app has too many layers so it takes some time to strip it down